# It is the ?? of the Board to recommend changes

Tags: single-word-requests

> It is the ?? of the Board to recommend changes.

I am looking for the correct missing word in this sentence. The person who wrote it used 'province' which is obviously wrong and I thought it should be 'provenance' but the dictionary does not back me up on this.

What they are trying to say is that it is the Board's responsibility or authority to do something.

'Prerogative' is a possibility but doesn't quite cut it as it acknowledges they can do something, not necessarily that is is in the scope of their activities.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaken about *province* being wrong. [Per the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/153460?redirectedFrom=province#eid):

> 9. A sphere of action, influence, or responsibility; the proper function or area of concern of a particular person or group; duty, business.

A few citations include:

> - 1888   ‘M. Robertson’ Lombard St. Myst. xii. 118 
>     How he had secured an entrance..it is not our province to inquire.
> - 1921   L. Strachey Queen Victoria iii. 79 
>     The foreign policy of England was not his province; it was hers and her Ministers'.
> - 1958   G. Greene Our Man in Havana ii. i. 70 
>     Dr. Hasselbacher never talked in terms of morality; it was outside the province of a doctor.
> - 1988   S. Quinn Mind of her Own vii. 139 
>     In the early nineteenth century, psychic life had been viewed in Germany as the province as much of philosophy as of medicine.

So there is nothing wrong with their use of the word *province* to mean duty or area of concern.

Comment: It may work semantically, but one doesn't usually see this in business texts: The board has the responsibility to recommend changes. Or use responsibility or purview.

Answer (score 2):

[***Remit***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remit), would be my first choice for a legal/corporate context -

*the task or area of activity officially assigned to an individual or organization* -

although this sense seems to be [more British than American English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remit)...?

For example:

> *The committee was becoming caught up in issues that did not fall within its **remit***;
>
> *The **remit** of this official inquiry is to investigate the reasons for the accident;*
>
> *It is within the **remit** of the Board to recommend changes.*

Comment: It is British English. But it is not incorrect at all.

Comment: Thanks - I like remit better than province. I will suggest it.